# Give permissions to a non-admin user for custom rules components

Tags: users, views, actions

I have a view, format: table; and a few fields:

1. Bulk operations: Content
2. Content: Title
3. Content: Price
4. Content: Stock 1 (Stock 1)
5. Content: Stock 2 (Stock 2)
6. Content: Stock 3 (Stock 3)
7. Global: Math expression (Total Stock)
8. Global: Math expression (Total Price)

At `Configure field: Bulk operations: Content` section `SELECTED BULK OPERATIONS` i selected **Delete item** and another 3 options (rules components). These are: **new_value_for_stock_1**, **new_value_for_stock_2**, **new_value_for_stock_3**, **new_value_for_price**.

Admin user can see all these options (rules components), but a non-admin user (eg. an **editor** role) can see only **Delete item**.

Is there a method (trick) to give permissions for a non-admin user (role)?

I enabled **Actions permissions (VBO)** and in `Administration » People » Permissions` are displayed only default actions (eg. EXECUTE Delete item). The custom rules components aren' displayed there.

Comment: If you give 'Bypass content access control' permission to a non-admin user, he'll be able to see these custom rules components.

Comment: Granting the above permission is very dangerous as allows unrestricted access to add/edit/delete content ^ You just need to check the *"Configure access for using this component with a permission"* as milkovsky answered below.

Answer (score 3):

You can set permissions on rule component page in fieldset at the page bottom.

There is an option "Configure access for using this component with a permission."